# How to pivot in Redshift without knowing the exact number of columns

Tags: dynamic, pivot, amazon-redshift

When running a query I get this result:

```
+------+-------+--------+
| type | site  | volume |
+------+-------+--------+
| 1    | alpha | 1000   |
+------+-------+--------+
| 1    | beta  | 3000   |
+------+-------+--------+
```

How could I pivot this so that I can get the following instead:

```
+------+-------+------+
| type | alpha | beta |
+------+-------+------+
| 1    | 1000  | 3000 |
+------+-------+------+
```

**N.b.** the `site` column is growing constantly so I don't know beforehand all the values.

I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1499

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible in redshift. maybe you could rethink what you are trying to achieve and do it a different way. feel free to expand your question.

Comment: Mention the structure of your source table (from where you're fetching data) as well.